# sitecore roles and workflow

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, user-roles, security-roles

I have a requirement where the roles are content authors, content reviewers, and publishers.

Content authors should be able to submit content, content reviewers can create, edit, and approve content, and publishers can do all of these things (create, edit, approve, publish) but cannot be an author and publisher at a time.

I created the roles as below:

**Content author:**

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users

**Content reviewer:**

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing

**Publisher**:

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing

So my idea is to create a workflow with the commands draft, submit, approve and reject, and assign the appropriate access for the workflow commands for the roles.

For publishers: is there a way that I can control the user's role, as the user cannot be a author and publisher at the same time?

Comment: Just to clarify you are trying to prevent your reviewers/publishers from being able to approve content that they changed?  In such if a publisher creates a new version of a document, you no longer want them to have access to approve that document and they would need to have someone else in a reviewer/publisher role approve the document?

Answer (score 1):

On the author role, explicitly deny read access to the publishing buttons in the interfaces (e.g. start menu, ribbons, etc.). By explicitly denying access, that takes precedence over any inherited access if they are both author and publisher, thus is negates any access they get from publisher.